# labeled sentiment words according to 8 different human sentiments

Tags: data-request, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to do sentiment analysis using lexicon based sentiment analysis. My goal is detecting 8 different basic sentiments (**not positive and negative sentiment only**). I found there is plenty of word dictionary for two class sentiment only, but I need 8 different word dictionary where words are being labeled according to their sentiment level. e.g. for say, this is a **fear dictionary** where words are being labeled in a `0-5` range.

`words  sentiment polarity
loser      -4
evil       -3
terrorist  -5`

I googled a lot but could not find actually such dictionaries. Looking for suggestions from experts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [NRC Word-Emotion Association Lexicon](http://saifmohammad.com/WebPages/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon.htm) has something that I was looking for.

> The NRC Emotion Lexicon is a list of English words and their associations with eight basic emotions (anger, fear, anticipation, trust, surprise, sadness, joy, and disgust) and two sentiments (negative and positive). The annotations were manually done by crowdsourcing.